# Can I save my Findstr result in a variable?

Tags: batch-file

I have this CSV:

```
The;Quick;Brown;Fox
```

I know how to get the String:

```
findstr /v "*" brownfox.csv
```

But how can i safe this string in a variable without using a For loop.

I want to process the string here to get the token count %i%

```
set var1=(the string from brownfox.csv)
set var2=%var1%
set i=0

:loopprocess
for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in ( "%var1%" ) do (
  set /A i+=1
  set var1=%%B
  goto loopprocess )

echo The string contains %i% tokens.
```

I just need the whole text in the CSV in a variable.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('findstr /v "*" brownfox.csv') do set "res=%%A"`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you cannot use `for`, but if you *absolutely cannot* use it, you need a temporary file:

```
>%TEMP%\foo.tmp findstr /v "*" brownfox.csv
<%TEMP%\foo.tmp set /p "var1="
```

However, from what you describe you don't need the variable at all. *And* you use a `for` loop anyway. Why not simply do

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in ('findstr /v "*" brownfox.csv') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set "var1=%%B"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<brownfox.csv set /p "line="
FOR %%G IN (%line%) DO set /a count+=1
echo The string contains %count% tokens.
```

first line to get the (first line of) the file, second to count the tokens, third to write it to screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just one other option for you. This splits the string up into a pseudo array of variables and also gives you a count of the number of variables in the array.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=1
set /p "x="<brownfox.csv
set "x!i!=%x:;=" & set /A i+=1 & set "x!i!=%"
set x
echo %i%
pause
```

[This technique was discovered in this thread on DosTips.com.](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)